# ingress-nginx permanent redirect 301 not working

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

> **UPDATE:** This problem solved itself. I can't tell why. I just tried again the next day and it worked with the config below.

I'm using the ["ingress-nginx"](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) ingress controller (v. 0.12.0). It works fine except for [permanent redirects](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/5c016bee873de5b83e6dad962f66e6a96cd73fa1/docs/user-guide/annotations.md#permanent-redirect).

In order to redirect `foo.example.com` to `https://google.com` I applied the following ingress config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: "https://google.com"
  name: redirect-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: default-backend 
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - foo.example.com
    secretName: domains-tls
```

But if I enter `foo.example.com` in the browser I get this:

> We're sorry, but we were unable to process the redirection request for the site you are attempting to access.
>
> If you feel that you are receiving this message in error, please check the URL and try your request again.
>
> UT
>
> (RF)

Does anyone know what goes wrong here?

Comment: wildguess: try putting `path: /` along with the backend item in paths?

Comment: Can you check in the browser's developer console to which address it trying to redirect you? Your configuration looks good.

Comment: Ok, this was a strange one... The next day I try it again and it works. I think I'll leave this here. Might be useful for someone else, idk.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue,

I fixed it by upgrading the nginx-ingress chart from `nginx-ingress-0.8.13` to `nginx-ingress-0.22.0`

I assume the permanent redirect annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect` did not existed in `0.8.13`.

So either helm upgrade your chart or upgrade your nginx-ingress directly.